# Let $G$ be a multiplicative group and $\varnothing\neq H\subseteq G$. Show that $H\le G$ iff both $H\circ H\subseteq H$ and $H^{-1}\subseteq H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

**Question:** Let $G$ be a multiplicative group and $H$ be a nonempty subset of $G$. Show that $H$ is subgroup if, and only if, $H\circ H \subseteq H$ and $H^{-1} \subseteq H$.

At the same time it seems to be very obvious, because when I verify the condition that $(a\circ b^{-1})$, I'm operating two elements of $H$ and it's inside $H$, byeond that, one this elements is an inverse of $H$.

But I don't know how can I write it down... So I need some help, please and thank you all!

Comment: What is your definition of subgroup?

Comment: This is the [two-step subgroup test.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Two-Step_Subgroup_Test)

Comment: A subgroup is a subset that is also a group.  A group must be closed, associative, and have inverses.

Comment: Don't forget the identity, @DougM. An inverse semigroup $S$ can exist in which there is no identity but inverses in sense of $a=aba$ and $b=bab$ hold for all $a,b$ in $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is a non-empty subset which is closed under composition and inversion and contains the identity element of $G$, that is

- $h_1,h_2\in H\implies h_1\circ h_2\in H$
- $e\in H$, where $e$ is the identity element of $H$
- $h\in H\implies h^{-1}\in H$

As you correctly noted, these conditions are equivalent to $g,h\in H\implies g\circ h^{-1}\in H$ (which is sometimes called the [One-Step subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Subgroup_Test)) for non-empty subsets $H\subseteq G$.

Now, regarding your question. It is clear that $H$ being a subgroup implies the two inclusions. On the other, these inclusion can be reexpressed as

- $H\circ H\subseteq H\iff h_1,h_2\in H\implies h_1\circ h_2\in H$
- $H^{-1}\subseteq H\iff h\in H\implies h^{-1}\in H$

As you can see, these are basically the defining property of being a subgroup rewritten in terms of set inclusions. What is not included here is that the identity of $G$ resides in $H$. But as we have at least one $h\in H$, $H$ being non-empty, we also have $h^{-1}\in H$ and then $h,h^{-1}\in H\implies h\circ h^{-1}=e\in H$ which concludes the proof.

Of course, the One-Step subgroup test applies directly as you correctly noted. Anyway, it might be worth adding the perspective of reformulating subgroup properties in terms of set inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

In one direction:

First of all, You must prove that $H\circ H\subset H$, but you have this for definition, because $H$ is a subgroup.In other words, for every $a,b\in H$, you have $ab\in H\circ H$, and, obviously, $ab\in H$. It will be quite similar to prove that $H^{-1}\subset H$, since if $a\in H$ then $a^{-1}\in H$.

The other direction:

Take $a,b \in H$, by hypothesis you have that $H\circ H \subset H$, then $ab\in H$. 
The second hypothesis says that $H^{-1}\subset H$, therefore you have inverses in $H$. You have too identity element because for every element in $H$, you have its inverse, and the rmultiplation is on $H$ too, this element is the identity.